# No such Element, Python 3.7

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe')


USERNAME = input ('Enter IXL Username: ')
PASSWORD = input ('Enter IXL Password: ')
LESSONNN = input ('Enter Lesson Link:  ')

driver.get(LESSONNN)
driver.refresh()

USERNAMEBOX = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qlusername"]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qlusername"]').click()
USERNAMEBOX.send_keys(USERNAME)

PASSWORDBOX = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qlpassword"]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qlpassword"]').click()
PASSWORDBOX.send_keys(PASSWORD)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qlsubmit"]').click()
time.sleep(3)

QUESTION1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('old-space-indent').text
print(QUESTION1)

driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.mathpapa.com/algebra-calculator.html', 'new_window')")

time.sleep(20)
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="source3"]')
ele.click()

driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])

answerbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fillIn')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('fillIn').click()
answerbox.send_keys(answer1)

submitbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yui_3_18_1_1_1613027229296_179"]/div[2]/button')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yui_3_18_1_1_1613027229296_179"]/div[2]/button').click()
```

I get the error

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

I tried driver wait and other options, none seem to work for me.
I need help making it wait until the element is present other wise it wont work.
Please help me nothing seems to work i cant seen to figure out why im getting this error as i created a new project with the same code and it works but it wouldnt work in this project.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you should add full error message and describe which line of code makes problem. Don't expect that we will run code to see full error message - besides you didn't add URL so we can't run it. So at this moment your question is only waste of time.

Comment: Understood. This is my first time, thanks.